# Magento Transactional Email Template

Tags: php, email, magento

I'm currently in the process of finalizing a custom controller to accept Ajax request for a quote form. I have been able to successfully set up everything, and it is sending properly. The question I have is relating to the method of linking a 
Transactional e-mail template from the CMS to the controller I have set up.

I have a template in the locale of the Magento install, and have been able to load it into the Transactional email manager of the backend. How would I be able to get the id of that template and load it into the mail object? I have attempted using the simple numerical id, and that doesn't seem to be working.

Config.xml

```
    <global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_quote>
                <label>Custom Quote Form</label>
                <file>custom-quote.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_quote>
            <trade_printer>
                <label>Trade Printer Form</label>
                <file>trade-printer.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </trade_printer>
        </email>
    </template>
    </global>
```

Comment: can you share you config.xml?

Comment: Relevant snippet added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading up on the available methods, I discovered that
`loadDefault()` will always load the template from the locale codebase. Utilizing `loadByCode()` with the name specified in the Transactional Email editor will load the customized template.

Final Code

`$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('Template Name Here');`

Answer (score 1):

this is a sample code for sending email with email template

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->loadDefault('custom_quote');                                  


$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = 'Branko';
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = 'Ajzele';
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = 'ActiveCodeline';
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate->send('john@someemail.com','John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
```

[reference](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/)

Comment: I appreciate the help, but as I stated in the second half of my question, I was able to link to a template located in the locale folder, but I wanted to be able to utilize the customized version located in the CMS Transactional Email settings. I have since discovered the loadByCode() method, which does exactly what I wanted.